# How to fetch PL/pgSQL cursors?

Tags: plpgsql

I am trying to get dynamic data using cursors :

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc(refcursor, refcursor) RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS $$
BEGIN
    OPEN $1 FOR SELECT * FROM users;
    RETURN NEXT $1;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When i try to fetch data i keep getting this error  : "a" is not a known variable ??

```
do $$ begin

SELECT * FROM myfunc('a', 'b');

FETCH ALL FROM a;
COMMIT;
end;

$$
```

Comment: The calling `DO` statement is wrong for too many reasons: a) There is no `INTO` with the `SELECT` or `FETCH` b) you didn't `DECLARE` variable `a` c) you didn't assign the result of the `SELECT` to the variable.

Comment: Could you provide a working example ?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do with the data from the cursor?

Comment: I want to return the fetched data as a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is fetch the data from the cursor, you don't need PL/pgSQL code. All you need is a transaction, since cursors don't outlive a transaction. Don't mix up `BEGIN` from PL/pgSQL, which starts a code block, with `BEGIN` from SQL, which starts a transaction:

```
BEGIN;

SELECT * FROM myfunc('a', 'b');

FETCH ALL FROM a;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: One more question sir, if I have 2 cursors 'a' and 'b', how I would query the result in one record ? (if not a then b if not b then a )

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, and this sounds like a new question.